# Android Activity.setContentView(), smooth transition?

Tags: user-interface, android, animation

I'm developing my first Android game and I'm having a bit of difficulty making the UI as smooth as I would like. I've spent a couple of hours googling around with no luck, I'm probably just searching for the wrong thing.

I have two different XML layout resources where each layout contains just one SurfaceView subclass. When I call activity.setContentView(R.layout.second_layout) to transition from the first layout to the second layout there is a noticeable period of time where a black screen (with a small white bar along the top) is displayed in between the two views.

I've tried various things such as; constructing the second view manually at runtime (i.e not using a layout XML file), calling activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out) after activity.setContentView(R.layout.second_layout) and attempting to render to the canvas before the view has loaded (turns out the canvas is unavailable).

I don't see other games (or apps) having this issue so I presume there is a reasonably simple solution.

If you need some more information about my particular situation in order to help out then please let me know what information is missing. Any help would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Looking around I'm starting to wonder whether I should just be creating a separate Activity for the second layout. Initially I didn't want to create one as I didn't feel as though I needed one due to the way the game is setup and because of the transition that is being made.

Perhaps I'm not thinking in the Android mindset yet. Would using a separate Activity solve my dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** My answer below was written in 2010. Since then [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) have become the norm, particularly since Fragment nesting was made possible and the support library allows this functionality to be used in a backwards compatible fashion. As such, instead of transitioning to a new Activity to perform a new "user task", you can use the one Activity and push and pop fragments within that Activity's view hierarchy. Animations can also be performed as a part of a fragment transaction (e.g. [Fragment transaction animation: slide in and slide out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026409/fragment-transaction-animation-slide-in-and-slide-out)).

This became pretty apparent not long after posting this question, however I thought I should come back here and make it clear to everyone else.
Activities are positively the way to go when developing for Android. Don't be put off by the fact that a transition may seem too minor for a separate Activity, the very foundation of Android is [built around the idea of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask).