# Fragment transaction animation: slide in and slide out

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I've check some tutorials for animate transaction between fragments. I've used this method for animation and it works:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

But I want to invert this animation: old fragment slide out to the left, and new fragment slide in to the right, but no value of `R.anim` file seems to be useful for my scope.

How can I do it?

Comment: in my opinion you could try to `override` `key_code==back_key_press` in your second fragment.

Comment: maybe i'm not explane myself well. I want that when fragment swap, old fragment slide on the left side, and new fragment enter from right. With that code the behavior is opposite

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886669/how-to-reverse-fragment-animations-on-backstack

Answer (score 306):

**UPDATE** [For Android v19+ see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760299/android-fragmenttransaction-custom-animation-unknown-animator-name-translate) via @Sandra

You can create your own animations. Place animation XML files in `res > anim`

enter_from_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate 
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

exit_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate 
      android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
      android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

exit_to_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%p"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

you can change the duration to short animation time

```
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
```

or long animation time

```
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
```

**USAGE** 
(note that the order in which you call methods on the transaction matters. Add the animation before you call .replace, .commit):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: simply use these xml animations when replacing fragments, i.e.:   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragDettRisorsa);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: its saying unknown animator name : translate

Comment: It doesn't work... caused "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate". This solution worked for me.  http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/

Comment: Duration `700` is a bit much for such animations, in my opinion. The Android framework has 3 presets for timing: `android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"`, `android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"` and `android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"`, which corresponds to 500, 400 and 200. I guess the unit is milliseconds, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the new apis (at least > 19) only support objectAnimator. You can check out another solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760299/android-fragmenttransaction-custom-animation-unknown-animator-name-translate

Comment: @Sandra I went ahead and updated the solution to point people in that direction if they have API v19+

Comment: Please note that by using `fragmentTransaction.replace()` as mentioned by @moondroid , you may be causing fragments to hit lifecycle events unnecessarily when the user presses the back button as compared to `fragmentTransaction.add()`. But, if you use `.add()`, you're not going to get as nice of an animation :) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684520/1738090

Comment: works only when using support fragments (android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Comment: Support fragments and support library 24.0.0, this solution works perfectly fine.

Comment: make sure to set the animations before calling .replace()

Comment: @nickaknudson How can you do this in code rather than xml files?

Comment: i got start animation but i could not getting exit animation, i am trying this animation on "Add" fragment.

Comment: i got slide animation from right to left on add fragment but whenever i press back it is not sliding from right to left . any idea?

Comment: Is there a way to use the default animation as used for Activities ?

Comment: To animate in reverse(when back pressed) you have to add two more animation parameters like this: transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);

Answer (score 50):

There is three way to transaction animation in fragment.

## Transitions

> So need to use one of the built-in Transitions, use the setTranstion()
>   method:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setTransition( FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN )
        .show( m_topFragment )
        .commit()
```

## Custom Animations

You can also customize the animation by using the setCustomAnimations() method:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.slide_up, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_down)
        .show( m_topFragment )
        .commit()
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1280"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1280"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

## Multiple Animations

> Finally, It's also possible to kick-off multiple fragment animations
>   in a single transaction. This allows for a pretty cool effect where
>   one fragment is sliding up and the other slides down at the same time:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.abc_slide_in_top, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top ) // Top Fragment Animation
        .show( m_topFragment )
        .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom ) // Bottom Fragment Animation
        .show( m_bottomFragment )
        .commit()
```

[To more detail you can visit URL](https://www.swarmnyc.com/whiteboard/android-fragment-animations)

**Note:-** You can check animation according to your requirement because above may be have issue.

Comment: You are using absolute hard-coded value. The previous fragment will disappear in the middle of screen for higher resolution displays.

Comment: @TheLibrarianCz this is just example

Comment: It is and it isn't.

Comment: it depend that some one want spoon feeding from above example or taking lesson what they can achieve with example.

Comment: what is in m_topFragment variable

Comment: @DPrince its ur fragment

Comment: Can we set the transitions while adding the fragment itself ? or do we need to set them after adding fragment ?  Can we do something like this?  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomTransitions().add(
                            binding.fragmentContainer.id, MyFragment())
                        ).commit()

Answer (score 11):

slide_in_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

slide_out_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        />
</set>
```

slide_out_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
        />
</set>
```

direction = down

```
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_down)
                    .replace(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                    .commit();
```

direction = up

```
           activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up)
                    .replace(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                    .commit();
```

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue, i used simple solution

1)create sliding_out_right.xml in anim folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
    </set>
```

2) create sliding_in_left.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

3) simply using fragment transaction setCustomeAnimations() with two custom xml and two default xml for animation as follows :-

```
 fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.sliding_in_left, R.anim.sliding_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution which I use:

```
public class CustomAnimator {
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.CustomAnimator";

    private static Stack<AnimationEntry> animation_stack    = new Stack<>();

    public static final int                 DIRECTION_LEFT  = 1;
    public static final int                 DIRECTION_RIGHT = -1;
    public static final int                 DIRECTION_UP    = 2;
    public static final int                 DIRECTION_DOWN  = -2;

    static class AnimationEntry {
        View in;
        View    out;
        int     direction;
        long    duration;
    }

    public static boolean hasHistory() {
        return !animation_stack.empty();
    }

    public static void reversePrevious() {
        if (!animation_stack.empty()) {
            AnimationEntry entry = animation_stack.pop();
            slide(entry.out, entry.in, -entry.direction, entry.duration, false);
        }
    }

    public static void clearHistory() {
        animation_stack.clear();
    }

    public static void slide(final View in, View out, final int direction, long duration) {
        slide(in, out, direction, duration, true);
    }

    private static void slide(final View in, final View out, final int direction, final long duration, final boolean save) {

        ViewGroup in_parent = (ViewGroup) in.getParent();
        ViewGroup out_parent = (ViewGroup) out.getParent();

        if (!in_parent.equals(out_parent)) {
            return;
        }

        int parent_width = in_parent.getWidth();
        int parent_height = in_parent.getHeight();

        ObjectAnimator slide_out;
        ObjectAnimator slide_in;

        switch (direction) {
            case DIRECTION_LEFT:
            default:
                slide_in = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(in, "translationX", parent_width, 0);
                slide_out = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(out, "translationX", 0, -out.getWidth());
                break;
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                slide_in = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(in, "translationX", -out.getWidth(), 0);
                slide_out = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(out, "translationX", 0, parent_width);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_UP:
                slide_in = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(in, "translationY", parent_height, 0);
                slide_out = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(out, "translationY", 0, -out.getHeight());
                break;
            case DIRECTION_DOWN:
                slide_in = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(in, "translationY", -out.getHeight(), 0);
                slide_out = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(out, "translationY", 0, parent_height);
                break;
        }

        AnimatorSet animations = new AnimatorSet();
        animations.setDuration(duration);
        animations.playTogether(slide_in, slide_out);
        animations.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                out.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (save) {
                    AnimationEntry ae = new AnimationEntry();
                    ae.in = in;
                    ae.out = out;
                    ae.direction = direction;
                    ae.duration = duration;
                    animation_stack.push(ae);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                in.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        animations.start();
    }
}
```

The usage of class. Let's say you have two fragments (list and details fragments)as shown below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ui_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Usage**

```
View details_container = findViewById(R.id.details_container);
View list_container = findViewById(R.id.list_container);
// You can select the direction left/right/up/down and the duration
CustomAnimator.slide(list_container, details_container,CustomAnimator.DIRECTION_LEFT, 400);
```

You can use the function `CustomAnimator.reversePrevious();`to get the previous view when the user pressed back.

Comment: are you sure you're using android's Fragments? =)
seems like using custom fragment-management view-based system)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with white screen during transition from one fragment to another. Have navigation and animations set in action in navigation.xml.

[image]

Background in all fragments the same but white blank screen. So i set navOptions in fragment during executing transition

```
          //Transition options
        val options = navOptions {
            anim {
                enter = R.anim.slide_in_right
                exit = R.anim.slide_out_left
                popEnter = R.anim.slide_in_left
                popExit = R.anim.slide_out_right
            }
        }

.......................

  this.findNavController().navigate(SampleFragmentDirections.actionSampleFragmentToChartFragment(it),
                    options)
```

It worked for me. No white screen between transistion. Magic )

Answer (score 0):

For me the only way I was able to get rid of the white background on the animation is if I changed to a DialogFragment instead of a Fragment and added the following code:

Created the following styles:

```
<style name="WindowSlideInAndOutAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_top</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppFullScreenDialogTransparentTitleBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Then reference these styles in the dialog fragment as such:

```
override fun getTheme() = R.style.AppFullScreenDialogTransparentTitleBar

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(R.style.WindowSlideInAndOutAnimation)

//rest of code on view created here
}
```

Then I just navigate to the fragment as normal via the navigation component (also note to change the type in the navigation xml file for the fragment to be dialog)