# How to realize this custom popup menu with Material Design Android?

Tags: android, menu, material-design

I want to realize a custom popup menu like [**Twitter**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android) in Android for example with item and picture but I don't know what's the component used for that.

In Material Design website, google present [this solution](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar). So I think, there is a native solution to achieve this.

[image]

I tried with [**Popup menu**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu), but I can't find how to customize the layout of this view like that.

Comment: Hi Lopez, Please try my code and let me know is it working or not. Thanks :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use a [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow.html), submitting your custom adapter, through which you can control the layout of every single row of the `ListPopupWindow`. As for a normal `PopupWindow` you have to provide an anchor view and additionally you have to call  `setContentWidth` on the instance of `ListPopupWindow`, which sets  the width of the popup window by the size of its content. It is a small price you have to pay, but for a small dataset is not a big deal. I have this utility method to retrieve the max width of the row:

```
public int measureContentWidth(ListAdapter adapter) {
    int maxWidth = 0;
    int count = adapter.getCount();
    final int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    View itemView = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        itemView = adapter.getView(i, itemView, this);
        itemView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, itemView.getMeasuredWidth());
    }
    return maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: How would you get the row to have that material theme?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I would use styles.xml

Comment: What style would you inherit from? I'm struggling with that, both for the rows and for the ListView containing them.

Answer (score 4):

There's a widget called `PopupMenu` which is basically a menu anchored to a specific view. One drawback is that it doesn't display icons by default.

However, you can use reflection and call `setForceShowIcon` to reveal them. The code that you need is:

- Since a `PopupMenu` is anchored to a specific view, your `ActionBar` item has an `actionLayout` attribute. That layout (`action_item.xml`) can be as simple as:

  ```
  <Button
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="Show popup"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  ```
- `ActionBar` menu style that contains your item with the above layout

  ```
  <menu
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/popup_item"
          android:title="Show popup"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/action_item"/>
  </menu>
  ```
- Your `popup_menu.xml`, the layout you'll inflate for your `PopupMenu`

  ```
  <menu
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:title="Item1"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
  </menu>
  ```
- And finally code to perform the inflation when an `ActionBar` item is clicked

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.action_add_item:
              PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, item.getActionView());
              MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

              // Use reflection to invoke setForceShowIcon
              try {
                  Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                  for (Field field : fields) {
                      if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                          field.setAccessible(true);
                          Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                          Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class
                                  .forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                          Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper
                                  .getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                          setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              popup.show();
              return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

Note, that to get that multi-line text in a menu, you'd need to use an `actionLayout` for your popup menu items too.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Pop-Up list fragment](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu/src/com.example.android.actionbarcompat.listpopupmenu/PopupListFragment.html).
The nice thing about fragments is that you can easily [animate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026409/fragment-transaction-animation-slide-in-and-slide-out) 
(If you don't understand fragments I recommend first reading [Fragment Introduction](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html))

If you want complete control over the pop-up content then see [Dialog Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue.but finally i found at my own solution that i am sharing you my code. Hope that will help you.

> ```
> popupWindowDogs = popupWindowDogs();
>     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>             // popupWindowDogs.showAsDropDown(v, -5, 0);
>             popupWindowDogs().showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
>         }
>     });
>     // Detect touched area
>     detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> public PopupWindow popupWindowDogs()
> {
>
>     // initialize a pop up window type
>     PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
>
>     // the drop down list is a list view
>     final ListView listView = new ListView(this);
>     // set our adapter and pass our pop up window contents
>     listView.setAdapter(dogsAdapter(popUpContents));
>     // listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
>     listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ss4);
>     listView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
>     listView.setDivider(null);
>     try {
>
>         listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
>                 View c = listView.getChildAt(0);
>                 String cc = listView.getChildAt(0).toString();
>                 int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
>                 /*
>                  * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), scrolly + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
>                  * .show();
>                  */}
>
>             @Override
>             public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
>                     int totalItemCount) {
>
>             }
>         });
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
>                 .show();
>     }
>     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
>                 long arg3) {
>             try {
>
>                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                 Context mContext = v.getContext();
>                 Swipetouch mainActivity = ((Swipetouch) mContext);
>                 // add some animation when a list item was clicked
>                 Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),
>                         android.R.anim.fade_in);
>                 fadeInAnimation.setDuration(10);
>                 v.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
>                 // dismiss the pop up
>                 mainActivity.popupWindowDogs.dismiss();
>                 // get the text and set it as the button text
>                 String val = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
>                 // Toast.makeText(mContext, val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 if (val.equals("Signup Now")) {
>                     Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration.class);
>                     startActivity(ii);
>                     stopService(new Intent(Swipetouch.this, MyService.class));
>                     stopService(new Intent(Swipetouch.this, MyService.class));
>                 } else if (val.equals("Login")) {
>                     Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyLoginActivity.class);
>                     startActivity(ii);
>                     stopService(new Intent(Swipetouch.this, MyService.class));
>
>                 } else if (val.equals("Exit")) {
>                     finish();
>                     stopService(new Intent(Swipetouch.this, MyService.class));
>                 } else if (val.equals("Friends")) {
>                     Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyLoginActivity.class);
>                     startActivity(ii);
>                 } else if (val.equals("Exit")) {
>                     stopService(new Intent(Swipetouch.this, MyService.class));
>                     finish();
>                 }
>
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 Toast.makeText(Swipetouch.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>         }
>
>     });
>     // some other visual settings
>     popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
>     popupWindow.setWidth(250);
>     // popupWindow.setHeight(300);
>     popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>
>     // set the list view as pop up window content
>     // SET WALLPAPER IMAGE
>     /*
>      * popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getWallpaper()); popupWindow.setHeight(300);
>      */
>     // layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sshadow);
>     // layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
>     // popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
>
>     popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
>             android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
>     popupWindow.setContentView(listView);
>
>     return popupWindow;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working in my app.

Try this :-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LocationDetailsActivity">


<item xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/title_of_menu"
    tools:context=".LocationDetailsActivity">
    //the menu list with icon
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_map_type_normal"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="some_icon" //place your icon here
            android:title="Vacation spots" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_map_type_satellite"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="some_icon" //place your icon here
            android:title="Friends and family" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_map_type_hybrid"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="some_icon" //place your icon here
            android:title="Restaurants" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

You can go through the tutorial from these different providers

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

All of them have great examples and source code to help you out

Hope this help you :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Dalm   Yes you are right. But these are the complete tutorials so its better to check the whole tutorial. I will add some main contents. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  try {
                    java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : fields) {
                        if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                            field.setAccessible(true);
                            Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                            Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class
                                    .forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                            Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper
                                    .getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                            setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Just dd this code before  popup.show();
it worked perfectttttllyyyy :)

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution. Add this just before you .show() method.

```
try {
  Field mFieldPopup=popupMenu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
  mFieldPopup.setAccessible(true);
  MenuPopupHelper mPopup = (MenuPopupHelper) mFieldPopup.get(popupMenu);
  mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```