# How to create a SimpleMenu as shown in the Material Design Documentation?

Tags: android, menu, material-design

I'm looking at the Material Design documentation for Menus, and they show what they call [SimpleMenus](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-behavior) that popup over items in a listview to allow you to change a specific item.  I'd like to use that in a custom ExpandableListView, but no matter how much I google I can't find anything suggesting how to achieve the graphics they're showing in their examples.  I've gotten fairly close with a PopupMenu, but the PopupMenu always shows up below the listview row that I touch, which appears consistent with the documentation for PopupMenu.

Is there a SimpleMenu somewhere I'm just not seeing?  Or something else I'm supposed to be using?

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184021/how-to-realize-this-custom-popup-menu-with-material-design-android/30476709#30476709) helps

Comment: That certainly looks like it'll push me in the right direction, but it also looks like I'll have to dig in quite a bit before it generates results.  Does google really have several pages of guidelines on how to make menus that aren't baked into android?  How dumb.