# Animate transaction between fragments when back button clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made right to left animation when fragment is being opened.
And now I need to make left to right animation when I click back button. I tried different solutions, but none of them worked. Please, help me.

In this video you can see that there is a right to left animation, but there is no left to right animation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNjiCwLpaqY&feature=youtu.be

My first fragment

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.exit_to_left);

            final Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            User user = (User)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);

            bundle.putString("name",user.getName());
            bundle.putInt("age",user.getAge());
            bundle.putString("speak",user.getSpeakingLanguage());
            bundle.putString("learn",user.getLearningLanguage());
            bundle.putInt("distance",user.getDistance());

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

My second fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((Main2Activity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((Main2Activity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    name = v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    speakingLanguage = v.findViewById(R.id.speaking_language);
    learningLanguage = v.findViewById(R.id.learning_language);
    ratingBar = v.findViewById(R.id.user_rating);
    distance = v.findViewById(R.id.location);

    if (bundle != null){
        name.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
        speakingLanguage.setText(bundle.getString("speaking"));
        learningLanguage.setText(bundle.getString("learning"));
        //ratingBar.setRating(bundle.getFloat("rating"));
    }else {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SessionManager.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        name.setText(preferences.getString("name",""));
        speakingLanguage.setText(preferences.getString("speaking","Speaking: Russian"));
        learningLanguage.setText(preferences.getString("learning","Learning: English"));
    }
    return v;
}
```

My MainActivity class

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            if (count == 0) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_left, R.animator.exit_to_right);

            ft.commit();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

exit_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment transaction animation: slide in and slide out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026409/fragment-transaction-animation-slide-in-and-slide-out)

Comment: @Alessandro.Vegna thanks, I tried that solution and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use overloaded version of `setCustomAnimations()`.

> setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)

Example:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_right, android.R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

EDIT:- for slide animation you can follow [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992609/4168607) its same what you have mentioned in question.

Comment: A tried this                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right,android.R.anim.slide_in_left, R.animator.exit_to_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

and got this
https://youtu.be/BkFbAHiOnVo

Maybe there is something wrong with my animations files? I added them to question

Comment: Yeah definitely. There is something wrong with animation  . Edited my answer . I have attached a link which you can follow.