# How to set slide out transition for fragment

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I'm applying transition set for entering fragment and for exiting i want to apply slide out animation, how can i do that, here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    productDetailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
    productDetailFragment.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    productDetailFragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));
}
((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                       .beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.fragment, productDetailFragment)
                       .addSharedElement(viewHolder.iv, "kittenImage")
                       .addToBackStack(null)
                       .commit();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026409/fragment-transaction-animation-slide-in-and-slide-out?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa have a look at this answer

Comment: what about if we want to set using setExitTransition?

Comment: yeah you can use that too see my answer.!

Answer (score 0):

**Call Fragment** :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("OtpFragment", 0);
Fragment fragment = null;
Bundle b = new Bundle();

if (!fragmentPopped && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("OtpFragment") == null) {
    fragment = new OtpFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_from_left);
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "OtpFragment")
               .addToBackStack("OtpFragment")
               .commit();
}
```

Create **anim** directory inside **res** folder :
now create two separate files for enter/exit animation : i.e. **R.anim.enter_from_right** and  **R.anim.exit_from_left**

Enter Slide Animation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Exit Side animation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Comment: what about if we want to set using setExitTransition?

Comment: not sure about that but :
**transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_from_left);** works for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for custom animation apply to fragment transitions:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations( R.anim.slide_up, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_down)
        .show( m_topFragment )
        .commit();
```

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1280"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1280"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Above i am showing you slide_up and down transition but you can use left-right and any custom objectAnimator to show animations into your fragment transition time and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.! may this work fine for you.!
 [Fragment Transaction Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.support.v4.app.Fragment&method=setExitTransition)

[Using Slide Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=android.transition.Slide)

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fade exitFade = new Fade();
exitFade.setDuration(FADE_DEFAULT_TIME);
previousFragment.setExitTransition(exitFade);
```

or

```
Transition slideTransition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
Transition fadeTransition = new Fade();
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.addTransition(slideTransition);
set.addTransition(fadeTransition);
```

Comment: its exit left, lilke slide not fade

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=android.transition.Slide check this

Comment: I tried, but slide and fade does not combine together